# Can flywaydb check the dependencies before deploying

Tags: flyway

We are planning to use Flaywaydb for our oralce db application deployments.

We are not sure if Flaywaydb figures out the dependancies between objects before deploying

Is there a ways we can set this dependencies at file level?

We know the file extension should be .sql but does it accepts any other extensions like pkb for example?

We appreciate your thoughts and suggestion on this.

Answer (score 0):

Flyway doesn't know about your database objects per se. It scans your classpath or filesystem for scripts and compares these to the ones it recorded in its schema_version table in the DB. It will then apply any newly added scripts.

You can extend Flyway through custom MigrationResolvers if you need to deal with custom formats, like pkb.